# How can get the content place holder hidden field values in the next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, hidden-field, form-post

I have two `aspx` pages , `bottle.aspx` and `cap.aspx`.

Once I fill the form in the `bottle.aspx` I should be able to submit that form to `cap.aspx` , which is working fine. But in `bottle.aspx` page I have `hidden fields` where am assigning the values to those `hidden fields` from the `JavaScript` function. Now when I try to get the `hidden field` values in the `cap.aspx.cs` file using `Request.Form["HiddenfiledId"]` I am getting the `null` value.

**`Bottle.aspx` code:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Meb.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="bottle.aspx.cs" Inherits="xxxx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MHead" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="NavBarContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Breadcrumbs" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MiddleColumnContent" runat="server">
    <style>
        .vTop {
            vertical-align: top !important;
        }

        .rd1 {
            margin: 1px 0px 0 6px;
        }

        .auto-style2 {
            margin-right: 294px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SelectSingleRadiobutton(rdbtnid,checked) {
            var rdBtn = document.getElementById(rdbtnid);

            var rdBtnList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (i = 0; i < rdBtnList.length; i++) {
                if (rdBtnList[i].type == "radio" && rdBtnList[i].id != rdBtn.id) {
                    rdBtnList[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
            if (checked == false) {
                document.getElementById("rbNewMessage").checked = false;
            }
            var hdnfldVariable = document.getElementById("hdnfldVariable")
            hdnfldVariable.value = rdbtnid;
        }
    </script>
    <form runat="server" method="post" action="Cap.aspx">
        <asp:gridview id="gvStatusMessages">
            <Columns>  
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="vTop rd1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSelectStatus" OnClick="javascript:SelectSingleRadiobutton(this.id,false)" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfldVariable" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:gridView>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit Message" ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="bluelink" OnClientClick="f1(this)" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfButtonClciked" runat="server" />
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Now in `cap.aspx.cs` file all i am trying to get the `hidden field` value.

```
 string btnClicked = Request.Form["hdfButtonClciked"];
 string msNum = Request.Form["hdnfldVariable"]
```

But it is returning `null` value.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try

**Approach1**

```
HiddenField btnClicked = ((HiddenField)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hdfButtonClciked")).Value;
HiddenField msNum = ((HiddenField)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hdnfldVariable")).Value;
```

Or

**Approach2**

Use `Session` instead of `HiddenField`.

Note: First approach is very likely to generate `NullReferenceException`, be careful to handle it.

Comment: it is neccessary to use server.transfer? Right. @Imad

Comment: @Rajan its your choice

Comment: I tried using the first approch in my cap.aspx.cs  its says .Value can't be used etc etc . so i gave  HiddenField btnClicked = (HiddenField)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hdfButtonClciked"); but still i get null value though i have posted value from the bottle.aspx.

Comment: when i use (HiddenField)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hdfButtonClciked‌​").Value, it gives a error saying control doesn't contain definition for 'value'..etc.

Comment: And i shouldn't use sessions it's an architect level decision though.

Comment: Try first approach now

Comment: when i try first approch (HiddenField)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hdfButtonClciked‌​‌​").Value, it gives a error saying control doesn't contain definition for 'value'.Then i removed .value  from the code ..i am not getting error and also am not getting the hidden field value given in the previous page.